# How to get automatic line-breaks using tabularx and makecell?♀

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx, makecell

I'm using the `tabularx` and `makecell` packages for the aesthetics of my tables. I used the `X` column type for columns with long texts and `\makecell{...}` for line-breaks into the cells. But when I try to use both together, the effect of the `X` columns doesn't work.

In the MWE I'd like that the long text um the 3rd line of the 1st row and last column breaks automatically. Any help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Table's caption}%
\label{tab:Example}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcX}%
\toprule
\textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2}   & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
Row 1           & 1                 & \makecell[lt]{Line 1\\Line 2\\\blindtext} \\
Row 2           & 2                 & \makecell[lt]{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3}     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: X columns allow line breaks anyway, (`\newline` or a blank line for a new paragraph) why `\makecell` ? `\makecell` is for cases like table headings where you only want forced line breaks and there is no automatic breaking)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry. I didn't know that I could do this

Comment: X columns are just `p` columns so you can do anything in an X column that you can do in a standard tabular `p` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could as well use `\makecell[Xt]{...}` (though, like @DavidCarlisle said, it doesn't really make sense):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Table's caption}%
\label{tab:Example}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcX}%
\toprule
\textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2}   & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
Row 1           & 1                 & \makecell[Xt]{Line 1\\Line 2\\\blindtext} \\
Row 2           & 2                 & \makecell[lt]{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3}     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp] % not [h]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Table's caption}%
\label{tab:Example}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcX}%
\toprule
\textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2}   & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
Row 1           & 1                 &
Line 1

Line 2

\blindtext
\\
Row 2           & 2                 &
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidCarlisle says, I used `\newline` to solve it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Table's caption}%
\label{tab:Example}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcX}%
\toprule
\textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2}   & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
Row 1           & 1                 & Line 1\newline Line 2\newline\blindtext\\
Row 2           & 2                 & \makecell[lt]{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3}     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why use `\makecell` in row 2?